# I want to show OK and cancel button in my alert dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to show ok and cancel  button in my alert dialog.I tried many solutions but didnt succeede..guide me plese..thanks

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Check Your Internet Connection!! you are not connected to the Internet..");

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                             alert.show();}
```

Comment: Less effort on search. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: OMG what a question???

Comment: @HCD I have tough questions as well..would you like to answer??

Comment: if u dnt mind have u search before u asking  ????

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
adb.setView(alertDialogView);
adb.setTitle("Title of alert dialog");
adb.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
adb.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        EditText et = (EditText)alertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
        Toast.makeText(Tutoriel18_Android.this, et.getText(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        finish();
    }
});
adb.show();
```

Comment: Nicolas> How would you change background color of this dialog box? Or an y other simple way to make it look a bit beautiful?

Comment: The *negative* event can also just be set to `null` : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25504486/756976

Comment: Better use `android.R.string.ok` and `android.R.string.cancel` instead of hard-coded strings "OK" and "Cancel"

Answer (score 7):

The following code will create a simple alert dialog with one button. In the following code `setTitle()` method is used for set Title to alert dialog. `setMessage()` is used for setting message to alert dialog. `setIcon()` is to set icon to alert dialog

```
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    AlertDialogActivity.this).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("Welcome to AndroidHive.info");

    // Setting Icon to Dialog
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);

    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
protected final Dialog onCreateDialog(final int id) {
    Dialog dialog = null;
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_ID:
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(
                "some message")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                //to perform on ok


                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {

                                //dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        dialog = alert;
        break;

    default:

    }
    return dialog;
}
```

you can call this from anywhere like:

```
      showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
```

Comment: you are assigning super class object to sub class ` dialog = alert;` wont it through exception?