# AlertDialog with OK/Cancel buttons

Tags: android, button, alert, android-alertdialog

I create this AlertDialog:

```
            String msg = "Connessione lenta o non funzionante";
            AlertDialog alertDialog;
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomePage.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Timeout connessione");
            alertDialog.setMessage(msg);
            alertDialog.show();
```

I want to add OK and Cancel buttons. I searched here on StackOverflow but setButton method seems to be deprecated. I also found setPositiveButton and setNegativeButton for AlertDialog.Builder but even them seem to be deprecated.

Comment: DEPRECATED...WHEN HOW ?

Comment: Everything about dialogs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: Why Do You think setPositiveButton and setNegativeButton are depecated? They are not...

Comment: Only `AlertDialog`.`setButton`/`setButton2`/`setButton3` are deprecated, but the `setButton(whichButton, ...)` and Negative/Positive/Neutral on `Builder` are not.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `AlertDialog.Builder.setPositiveButton` and `AlertDialog.Builder.setNegativeButton`, both are not deprecated ([see the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setPositiveButton(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener))):

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(HomePage.this)
        .setTitle("Timeout connessione")
        .setMessage("Connessione lenta o non funzionante")
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null) // dismisses by default
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // do the acknowledged action, beware, this is run on UI thread
            }
        })
        .create()
        .show();
```

Comment: Is there a way to control the order of negative vs positive button in AlertDialog?  Say I want cancel btn to go on the left...

Comment: Just invert the labels?

Comment: You mean `string.ok` for negative button, and `string.cancel` for positive button?

Comment: yes, unless you want to use the deprecated button_0/1, or having a custom View, I don't see any other option

Answer (score 4):

Use `alertDialog.setPositiveButton` and `alertDialog.setNegativeButton`, Here is a Utility Method you can use:

```
public static void ask(final Activity activity, String title, String msg,
                       DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener, 
                       DialogInterface.OnClickListener cancelListener) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);
    alertDialog.setMessage(msg);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, okListener);
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, cancelListener);
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
ask(mInstance, getString(R.string.app_name),
            getString(R.string.confirm_text_here),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { // OK
                    // do Something
                }
            }, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { // Cancel
                    // do Something
                }
            });
```

For more details refer [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
I usually use this code and It works perfectly use this  

  DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which){
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        finish();
                        break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Want To Do Some Task").setPositiveButton("Ok"), dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel"), dialogClickListener).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code i think it will work perfectly.

```
public void open(View view){
  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("alert dialog");
  alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("conform to delete");
  alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("ok", 
  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        Intent positveActivity = new                                                 Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.alertdialog.PositiveActivity.class);
        startActivity(positveActivity);

     }
  });
  alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("cancel", 
  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Intent negativeActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.alertdialog.NegativeActivity.class);
        startActivity(negativeActivity);
     }
  });

  AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
  alertDialog.show();
    }
```